# Unknown provider: eProvider <- e

Tags: angularjs

I'm updating a legacy Angular JS 1.7 app and adding an [AngularJS Material Popup modal](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog). The app uses Webpack and compresses when deploying to production (See below: `drop_console` = true).

**Webpack:**

```
new TerserPlugin({
    terserOptions: {
        compress: {
            drop_console: (isProduction) ? true : false, // true
        },
    },
}),
```

I'm aware that Angular requires the injected dependencies to be quoted, `.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {`, since minification changes the names of the dependencies, which may result in the error I'm getting:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e ...
```

But the way this modal works is by binding a controller function as such:

**Factory Service:**

```
angular.module('MODULE').factory('myService', ['$mdDialog', 
 function ($mdDialog) {
  return {

   ...

      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController, // bound to dialog controller below
        ...
      });

      function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) { // dependencies injected here
        ...
```

How do I provide quotes around the dependencies when they're inside a module, `function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 $mdDialog.show({
    controller: ['$scope', '$mdDialog', DialogController]
    ...
  });

 function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {/* ...*/}
```

---

As a side note, please avoid defining the dialogs inside services/factories.